# Is there a way to remove apaches Reverse Proxy Request Headers?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy, mod-headers

When acting as a reverse proxy, apache adds x-forwarded headers as described here.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers

In my configuration I have configured server A as a forward proxy. There is a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule proxy:(.*example.com)/(.*) $1.mysecondserver.com/$2 [P]
```

This rule lets the server request the resource from one of my other servers.

On the second server (origin) I have a virtual host container for the resource and another rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule some-regex some-url [P]
```

It may not seem to make sense like this but there is a lot of other stuff going on that I left out as it is not part of the problem.

However that final request has these headers:

```
[X-Forwarded-For] => ip of 1st server
[X-Forwarded-Host] => example.myseconserver.com
[X-Forwarded-Server] => example.com
```

I want those headers gone.

I seem to be unable to unset them with mod_headers. I can add more entries to them, but I can not remove them.

Any ideas?

Comment: The only way known to me is **[RequestHeader](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader)** from mod_headers: use to delete these headers, e.g. `RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For`. This directive has lower priority and runs **after** mod_rewrite just before the request is run by its handler in the fixup phase. I'm not sure about `X-Forwarded-*` headers, but it works fine for User Agent and similar headers -- no problems removing them

Comment: that is just what i tried but those headers seem not to be editable this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

corrected answer: there is no way to do that since its hardcoded

to fix this in the source code of mod_proxy_http.c search for the following part:

```
    apr_table_mergen(r->headers_in, "X-Forwarded-Server",
                 r->server->server_hostname);
}
```

and immediately after that add this code:

```
// remove any X-Forwarded headers
apr_table_unset(r->headers_in, "X-Forwarded-For");
apr_table_unset(r->headers_in, "X-Forwarded-Host");
apr_table_unset(r->headers_in, "X-Forwarded-Server");
```

then compile by running `apxs2 -cia mod_proxy_http.c`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you made mod_headers work to remove those headers?  I can't seem to in apache 2.2 no matter what I try.

Comment: sorry, i un-checked this answer because it does not work. if i remember that correctly there is no way and i ended up patching the module! however i have long switched to nginx since.

Comment: I think I'll just use Apache 2.4 which allows you to to use ProxyAddHeaders, unless I need more granular control - in which case I will switch to nginx too :)

Comment: i agree with you that this is probably the better way, especially considering nginx

Comment: To be clear, Apache 2.4 has http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyaddheaders which using ProxyAddHeaders Off should do as requested.

Answer (score 4):

Since Apache 2, as this pretty [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/728706/200053) says, the

```
ProxyAddHeaders Off
```

theoretically disables it. In my experiences, it had no effect. However, combined with

```
<Proxy *>
  ProxyAddHeaders Off
</Proxy>
```

and, with

```
  RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Host
  RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For
  RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Server
```

somewhere it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on httpd 2.2 on CentOS 5. Installing httpd 2.4 wasn't possible. But because of some reasons I couldn't switch to nginx completly. So I did it by inserting nginx proxy between httpd and the destination address. So I had: httpd(`localhost:80/path`) -> nginx(`localhost:81/path`) -> `http://your.destination/path`. Installation steps are the following:

1. Install nginx according to [these instructions](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#mainline)
2. Configure nginx to avoid security problems.
3. Add an location in nginx that will remove those httpd's reverse proxy request headers. It can look like this:

   ```
   location /path {
       proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for "";
       proxy_set_header x-forwarded-host "";
       proxy_set_header x-forwarded-server "";
       proxy_pass http://your.destination/path;
   }
   ```

Comment: can you give us more details on where to put the location /path ?

Comment: I have it in my "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" inside the "server" section. This is the way, you add "location" usually.