# SonarQube HTTP & HTTPS + reverse proxy : IP spoofing attack?

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

Sonarqube is deployed on a intranet server (=> http url).

When an https internet url is declared to access this server, using DMZ reverse proxy, this error occurs :

```
2013.11.22 19:47:53 ERROR rails  /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Fri Nov 22 19:47:53 +0100 2013
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  IP spoofing attack?!
HTTP_CLIENT_IP="[real.ip.deleted]"
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR="[real.ip.deleted]"
```

*Rails* has right, but this use case is acceptable (to propose SonarQube UI to suppliers, or when I want check my CI result on my Smartphne with my cofee time !).

The possibility to disable ip spoofing or uncheck proxy ip verification could be a great feature, configured **IN** *sonar.properties*

---

A workaround (tested in sonar 3.7.3) is set

```
File : [sonar-dir]/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb

@@ip_spoofing_check = false
```

But modify distribution is not sustainable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case seems to be specific with Apache 2.2 configured in reverse-proxy (*ProxyPass* directive), in front of SonarQube.

This version [always add 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers).

---

The best solution (compared to workaround exposed) is to upgrade in Apache 2.4.

The directive [**ProxyAddHeaders**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyaddheaders) could be used to control the add of this header.

---

Other stackoverflow thread : [is-there-a-way-to-remove-apaches-reverse-proxy-request-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312215/is-there-a-way-to-remove-apaches-reverse-proxy-request-headers)